# C# - Querying DynamoDB Global Secondary Index Error

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

**UPDATE**
I was completely off base with my approach. The following worked

```
public async Task<List<MarketCoordinate>> GetMarketCoordinates(String marketId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var query = new QueryOperationConfig
    {
        IndexName = "marketId-index",
        Filter = new QueryFilter("marketId", QueryOperator.Equal, marketId)
    };

    var results = await _context.FromQueryAsync<MarketCoordinate>(query).GetRemainingAsync(cancellationToken);
    return results;
}
```

================================================

**Original Question**

I have a table in DynamoDB called `MarketCoordinates_dev` with the following properties

```
id (string)
marketId (string and Fk to the Markets_dev table)
```

I have created a GSI called `marketId-index` with the Partition key being `marketId (String)` with default values.

I'm trying to query this table to only return results when the `marketId` matches the ID I'm passing in.

Here's my C# code

```
public async Task<List<MarketCoordinate>> GetMarketCoordinates(String marketId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = new QueryRequest
    {
        TableName = "MarketCoordinates_dev",
        IndexName = "marketId-index",
        KeyConditionExpression = "marketId = :mktid",
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<String, AttributeValue>
            {
                { ":mktid", new AttributeValue { S = marketId } }
            }
    };

    var results = await _context.QueryAsync<MarketCoordinate>(request).GetRemainingAsync(cancellationToken);
    return results;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.QueryRequest' to type 'System.String'.
```

My C# model looks like this

```
[DynamoDBTable("MarketCoordinates_dev")]
public class MarketCoordinate
{
  [DynamoDBHashKey("id")]
  public String Id { get; set; } = default!;

  [DynamoDBProperty("marketid")] 
  public String MarketId { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

I've been searching for an answer but have come up short. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's your index name, are you able to change it? Ideally it should be `marketIdIndex`.

Then your expression would work as it is:

```
`KeyConditionExpression = "marketId = :mktid",`
```